# Unused variable

Tags: xcode6, push

I have same warning in xcode (Unused variable 'conn').

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSString *token = [deviceToken description];
    token = [token stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"deviceToken"];

    NSData *postData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"token=%@", deviceToken] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    //Don't forget to change the API link to your own link
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                          @"http://mydomaine.com/push/savetoken/?device_token=%@&device_type=ios&channels_id=1", token]]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSLog(@"My device token is: %@", deviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the compiler is correct; you create an instance of `NSURLConnection` which will be immediately destroyed when it goes out of scope.

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

I suspect you want to keep a reference to the connection using an instance variable or `@property`:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
{
    NSURLConnection *_conn;
}
@end
```

and use:

```
_conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```